# TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined at onformsubmit(Code:10:17)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

[image: trigger installed]I am getting this error when running :`TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined at onformsubmit(Code:10:17)`
I have installed the `onformsubmit` trigger but it is not working. What is not working here?

```
function onformsubmit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var sheet = range.getSheet();

  sheet.getRange(row, 17).setFormula("=if($O"+row+"=\"UZS\",index(googlefinance(\"currency:UZSUSD\",\"price\",$B"+row+"),2,2)*$P"+row+",if($O"+row+"=\"EUR\",index(googlefinance(\"currency:EURUSD\",\"price\",$B"+row+"),2,2)*$P"+row+",$P"+row+"))");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely that you are running the `onformsubmit` function from the script editor which don't send an event object (`e`).

Note: The same happens with any function that use an object as parameter that use an object property,  no matter of the property name.

In order to run `onformsubmit` or any other function that requires an object as parameter from the Google Apps Editor for debugging purposes, you have to create a an auxiliary function to mock the event object and assign the required properties. For a broader explanation see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16089067/1595451) from Mogsdad to [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089041/1595451)

Related

- [How can I get my set values and formulas to populate to a row of values received from a Google Form?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/72982/88163)
- [Running a script from inside a sheet cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/104161/88163)
- [TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined at onformsubmit again after creating an event object](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/139838/88163)

Comment: even though I have created the event object the very error is occurring again

Comment: @AroonAdvisoryGroup Please create a new question including enough details to understand how do you created the event object and how you are using it.