# The script(onSubmmit Trigger) only works in the script editor and doesn't work when the form is actually submitted

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms, google-apps-script-triggers

This is a follow up of [How to send email to a person selected from a dropdown menuwith all answers of a response of the form submission?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/143104/88163)

I want to notify mentors if they're selected by a user on a Google Form. The names of the mentors are in a drop-down menu in the Google Form. This is the form: https://forms.gle/iNuA5nB2J9koKhXt6.

I'm storing responses in a spreadsheet, I've created a different worksheet in the same spreadsheet named "namenemail" in which I've stored the names and email IDs of the mentors. This is the spreadsheet:
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15xS_-I6Jw3cqx-00Ink4FFTcfmI3Zi-hBGlMU2x0Cb4/edit?usp=sharing.

I want to send an email to the mentor whose name is selected from the dropdown menu with all the answers from the response of Google Form submission on submit. I can't seem to get it right.

The Script that I'm using is working if I run it from the script editor (fixed range) but won't work for a new form submission.

The script is as follows:

```
function AutoConfirmation(e){
var e = {};
var afar = "15xS_-I6Jw3cqx-00Ink4FFTcfmI3Zi-hBGlMU2x0Cb4";
var Data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(afar).getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
numRows= Data.getLastRow();
e.range = Data.getRange('2:2');
e.values = e.range.getValues()[0];

//setup the spreadsheet
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

//get the range from OnFormSubmit
var range = e.range;
Logger.log("DEBUG: the range is "+range.getA1Notation());//DEBUG

// get the data for the range
var response = range.getValues();

// get the clinician name from the form submission
var mentor = response[0][3]; 
Logger.log("DEBUG: Mentor name = "+mentor);// DEBUG

// get the emails list
var emailSheet =    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("namenemail");
// get ALL the data from this sheet
var emaildata = emailSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

// check how many rows of data
var emailLastRow = emailSheet.getLastRow();
// start the loop through the emails data
for (var i=1; i<emailLastRow; i++){

// if the mentor is equal to Email
if (mentor == emaildata[i][0]){
// there is a match
//Next, get the email address
var emailmentor = emaildata[i][1];
Logger.log("DEBUG: clinician = "+emaildata[i][0]+", email address: "+emailmentor);// DEBUG

// Finally, send the Email.
var theirName = e.values[1];
var theirEmail = e.values[2];
var theEnquiry = e.values[5];
var subject = "New Form Submitted";
var message = "New Enquiry by: \n\n EMAIL: " + theirEmail + " \n Name: " + theirName + " \n\n     Regarding Enquiry: \n" + theEnquiry; 

MailApp.sendEmail(emailmentor, subject, message);
}
}
}
```

The trigger that I'm using is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling the function by using an on form submit installable trigger you should not include on the declaration of `AutoConfirmation(e)`:

```
var e = {};
```

and either

```
e.range = Data.getRange('2:2');
e.values = e.range.getValues()[0];
```

as the above lines will overwrite the event object and it's properties that were sent by the trigger.

To run your `AutoConfirmation` function from the script editor, you should create another function to pass to it an object with the required properties, i.e.:

```
function debug_AutoConfirmation(){

  var e = {};
  var afar = "15xS_-I6Jw3cqx-00Ink4FFTcfmI3Zi-hBGlMU2x0Cb4";
  var Data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(afar).getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var numRows = Data.getLastRow();
  e.range = Data.getRange('2:2');
  e.values = e.range.getValues()[0];

  AutoConfirmation(e)

}
```

For a broader explanation see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16089067/1595451) from Mogsdad to [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16089041/1595451)

Comment: thank you so much, this works great!