# not working form submit Event Object

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms

I have a Google form which I use to populate a Google docs from a certain template whenever a new response is submitted. In order to achieve this, I have written this script, but it is not working and showing this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined (line 3, file "Code")`:

```
function createdocs(e) {

  var Contracttype = e.values[1];
  var Partnername = e.values[2];
  var Bankname = e.values[3];
  var Accountnumber = e.values[4];
  var TIN = e.values[5];
  var Bankcode = e.values[6];
  var Businesscode = e.values[7];
  var Phone = e.values[8];
  var Director = e.values[9];
  var Contractstartingdate = e.values[10];
  var Contractendingdate = e.values[11];
  var EmailAddress = e.values[12];

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('10lZQhmbocTOmvGwklYnHNvXbdGXDmpbgFbvcnu67G7c'); 
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1O6QJZ5gRRoSUeolcVvKlMe65Wdb4rz9z')
  var copy = file.makeCopy(Partnername + ',' + Contractstartingdate, folder); 
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  var body = doc.getBody(); 

  body.replaceText('{{Partner name}}', Partnername);  
  body.replaceText('{{Bank name}}', Bankname);
  body.replaceText('{{Account number}}', Accountnumber);
  body.replaceText('{{TIN}}', TIN);
  body.replaceText('{{Bank code}}', Bankcode);
  body.replaceText('{{Business code}}', Businesscode);
  body.replaceText('{{Phone}}', Phone);
  body.replaceText('{{Director}}', Director);
  body.replaceText('{{Contract starting date}}', Contractstartingdate);
  body.replaceText('{{Contract ending date}}', Contractendingdate);

  doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

*I have used a youtube tutorial for this purpose and followed every step,  But I am failing, how to define `values` in the script, I have installed the `onformSubmit` trigger. But there is something going wrong* Please help me with this out

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined at onformsubmit(Code:10:17)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/139774/typeerror-cannot-read-property-range-of-undefined-at-onformsubmitcode1017)

Comment: The point I wanted to state is that ```onformsubmit``` trigger is not working when I install it manually. The problem is going with ```event object```, I suppose. Of course, what you suggested is working perfectly, but what is interesting me is why it is not working when installed manually in my case?!

Comment: @AroonAdvisoryGroup You are having this problem because you are running the script from the Script Editor. The property "values" only has a context when no context and that is why is is When you do this, "e.values"

Answer (score 0):

You are having this problem because you are running the script from the Script Editor. When you do this, the event objects aren't created - this is why "values" is described as *"undefined"*.

You are using an `onformsubmit` trigger and event objects are created **ONLY** when a form is submitted.

Your spreadsheet must contain the Response sheet for a form. When a form is submitted, the Response sheet is automatically updated and the script is triggered. At this point, the event objects (includes "values") can be accessed.